# PHP - Overriding properties

Tags: php, properties, overriding

Is there a way to prevent overriding properties in PHP? And if yes - how?

Comment: You mean like [public, protected or private](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)?

Comment: I have a protected property in class Base called pbase (as example) and I want to prevent overriding the property in child classes.

Comment: Make it [`private`](http://codepad.org/9sxXFi2X)?

Comment: When I make it private, I can't call it from child classes, but I want to prevent only overriding.

Comment: I think you need a method to retrieve your value, not a plain property.

Comment: Please provide more context to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do such a thing is playing with `__set()` in a class.
**But**, `__set` is only used for non accessible properties.

For public properties, i don't think there is any way to prevent overriding.

You should check out the official documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Thanks, but I know what means __set and can't help me, becouse my properties are declared.

Comment: So i don't think what you want to do is possible...
Try to find another way: store these protected variables in a private array, and access them using a specific __get

Comment: So whatever, I undeclared my properties and ... :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want:

```
class A{
    private $a;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->a = 'A';
    }
    public function __get($property){
        return $this->{$property};
    }
}

class B Extends A{
    public function getA(){
        return $this->a;
    }
    public function __get($property){
        return parent::__get($property);
    }
}

$b = new B;
echo $b->getA();
```

Comment: That only works if you want a method instead of a property, and if you control the child class definition.

Comment: No :(. I wan't to call this property AS PROPERTY :D Thanks.

Comment: @user997379 - You're going to have to show how you're needing it implemented; short answer, it doesn't sound possible for a [`final`-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) functionality in PHP without using a method.

Comment: Can yo please post some code with explanation where do you want to prevent property from being overridden and how you want to access them?

Comment: @JaredFarrish comment gave me a hint, if you don't want parent classes to have their own property named just as in base class, it is not possible in the moment (for properties, methods can be `final`).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: `const` is used for "final" properties, it just has the disadvantage of controlling the visibility as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TheBaseClass {

  private $nomod = 'foo';

  public function getNoMod() {
     return $this->nomod;
  }
}

class TheChildClass extends TheParentClass {
   public function funcUsesNomod(){
      return 'The value of nomod is '. $this->getNomod();
   }
}
```

Comment: To be fair to @dev-null-dweller, the OP seems to suggest a method won't work (it must be a property, for some reason). I have given you both upvotes, though.

Answer (score 0):

"Yeah", if you make them constants. See the answers to [How to implement a read-only member variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343790/how-to-implement-a-read-only-member-variable-in-php/2343799#2343799), don't skip the comments.

Example:

```
class user {
  const ALWAYS_ONE = 1;
}
```

I guess, declaring properties as `private` also prevents overloading but they are also inaccessible to the descending classes.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to call this property in child classes (it contains object) with a "property interface"

Comment: I think @Jared Farrish is right, use a method. (Hard to tell when you don't spell out the full scenario)